# Why doesn't `"hello\r".chomp('')` remove `"\r"`?

Tags: ruby, newline

Although the [Ruby reference manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-chomp) describes:

> If `$/` is an empty string, it will remove all trailing newlines from the string.

`"hello\r".chomp('')` doesn't remove `"\r"` as in the following.

```
"hello\r\n".chomp     # => "hello"
"hello\r".chomp       # => "hello"
"hello\r\n".chomp('') # => "hello"
"hello\r".chomp('')   # => "hello\r"
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $/ is an empty string, it will remove all trailing newlines from the string.

Exactly. `\r` AKA `CR` is not a newline character. It's a carriage return character (doesn't start a new line).

As to why `chomp('')` removes CRLF, it's because CRLF is a Windows-style newline. Linux uses LF.

Old Mac OSes (up to v9) were using CR, but recent ones (OS X) do not. So "CR as a newline char" does not exist as far as ruby is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

The short explanation is that `\r` is not a newline, but a carriage return. So `chomp()` does exactly what the manual states.

The long explanation can be found on the [Control_character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) Wikipedia page.